# Duplicate audio output to multiple devices in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio

Is there any way (or application/driver for this) to play audio from app to multiple output devices? Or even better - to just duplicate/mirror audio that is coming to one output device to another one.

I have found something like this: 
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/output-audio-to-multiple-devices-in-windows-10/b284def2-d684-4f1f-87a0-f562f556aedd
But I can't use it because I use bluetooth so my default windows output device always says "not plugged in", so I can't even confirm what it does.

My final goal is to redirect music application to both my headphones and virtual cable.

Comment: Just curious, even when the Bluetooth device is paired, turned on, and a video/audio is playing the media player.. there is no sound is coming out at all  (from the headphones ) ?

Comment: @p._phidot_ ? Not sure why you would get such idea, as long as I'm using headphones as my default output device it works fine. And that's the only output device I can set to default one. (+ virtual ones)

Comment: To share audio streams among multiple devices with Virtual Audio Cable, you first need to direct the sound to a Virtual Cable (for example, Line 1), then take multiple copies from the opposite cable side. Please see the [example](https://vac.muzychenko.net/en/usage.htm#SharingAmongDevices).

Comment: I thought of that because of this statement : "I can't use it because I use bluetooth so my default windows output device always says "not plugged in", " . If the bluetooth headphones is the Only default output, this statement(troubleshooting info)  seems invalid.

Comment: @p._phidot_ this solution requires to use default device provided by system - but for me that device can't be set to default because nothing is connected to it. So option to set it to default is just unavailable. So my default device are bluetooth headphones.

Comment: @EugeneMuzychenko oh, so I need this "Audio Repeater" app, not just virtual cables. Tho I would like to find some free alternative, so I can easily share this setup with some people. But thanks, you can post this as answer, if I will not find any alternative I will accept it. (and add comment & accept if I will find one)

Comment: Audio Repeater is required in such setup because the "Listen" Windows feature is bound to a recording endpoint, not to a playback one, so you can play recorded sounds to a single playback endpoint only.
Audio Repeater from VAC package can be used freely, you can extract it from VAC trial package, and use together with a free alternative.
Trial version of VAC starts to add a voice reminder after a hour since driver restart, so it can be used within a hour with no reminder.

Answer (score 3):

> To share audio streams among multiple devices with Virtual Audio
> Cable, you first need to direct the sound to a Virtual Cable (for
> example, Line 1), then take multiple copies from the opposite cable
> side. Please see the [example](https://vac.muzychenko.net/en/usage.htm#SharingAmongDevices). – [Eugene Muzychenko](https://superuser.com/users/1001813/eugene-muzychenko) Jun 15 '19 at 17:50

It's good to have an answer for people like me looking for something like this. https://vac.muzychenko.net/en/repeater.htm (at the bottom)

Comment: I found the original link/creator, with the updated version. Previously I thought this was the older, but free version, of a paid app (that wasn't the case). The answer has been updated with this link

Comment: I just realized Eugene is the creator of the repeater

Answer (score 1):

Windows finally has a built in function for this, though it is a bit clunky.

```
Right click volume control > "Sounds" > "Recording" > "Show Disabled Devices"
    Right click "Stereo Mix" > "Enable"
    Right click "Stereo Mix" > "Properties" > "Listen"
        Check "Listen to this Device"
        Chose secondary playback device
```

Credit:
https://windowsreport.com/use-2-audio-outputs-same-time-windows-11/

There are also free software solutions out there:
https://www.dxzone.com/5-free-virtual-audio-cable-software/

Comment: Same issue, it requires you to use the default speaker device, I don't use it, both devices are connected via different interface. Solving the issue using voice meeter so far, a bit annoying as it does not handle BT disconnects well (i need to "restart engine" each time i reconnect headphones) but works